# Formatting ASP.NET ReportViewer with CSS classes and online specific rules?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

How can I assign classes to the online/ASP.NET (not a desktop app) version of ReportViewer? I'm also intersted in using web specific formatting, e.g. ems versus ReportViewer desktop defaults such as points and inches.

Comment: Can you give more details. You use the designer to stylize your report (rdl rdlc).

http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/rajbk/image_54500E35.png

Comment: Raj - I know I can use the designer, that's sort of the basic step that I've done and laid things out but I want to go beyond and set IDs and classes on the ReportViewer so that I could format it using CSS.

Comment: So using your image - here's an example I would like to style "Contact Title" by adding a CSS class to it - How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out the solution. By default ReportViewer generates classes for the tables - they're still pretty cryptic - "a15" and "r11" which is not exactly my idea of identifying rows/columns/tables. But I guess it's better then nothing.

Comment: hello, can you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

- [Example 1](http://www.izenda.com/Site/KB/FAQ/How-do-I-change-the-CSS-of-the-Report-Viewer-Reportviewer.aspx-page)
- [Example 2](http://www.thisispaulsmith.co.uk/BLOG/post/Get-ASPNET-Report-Viewer-to-Occupy-10025-Height-and-Width-Crossbrowser!!.aspx)

Comment: Hey Kman, sorry that doesn't answer it. What I'm looking for is styling specific CELLS in the reportviewer... sorry if I didn't clarify this earlier. But the idea is to get specific and style the cells as they are laid out in the reportviewer. This is opposed to styling the table, I mean otherwise I could just copy and paste it's name off the source code that returns the aspx page.

Comment: Your second example is a private blog, which is invite only.